# Long-lived page tokens are unobtainable for some apps

Tags: migration, deprecated, access-token, facebook-access-token

Facebook's offline_access deprecation migration was scheduled to be released earlier this year.  However, it was delayed multiple times until October 3, presumably because it was buggy and had yet to be fully implemented.  As of this moment, the migration is still incomplete and error-prone.

After months and months of preparing for the change, updating our codebase, and repeated (futile) attempts to work with Facebook, this broken migration is set to go live within a week.

As detailed in a bug report (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/151056591697025), for our app, long-lived page access tokens (the alternative to using the offline_access permission) cannot be acquired.  Facebook seems to be giving the issue zero attention.

If Facebook continues to do nothing, on October 3, our app (along with many others) will break.  What should we do?

---

Update

The most conclusive evidence that something isn't working is the following workflow:

1. Confirmed that we receive a short-lived token for the user.
2. Confirmed that we can convert that short-lived token into a long-lived token.
3. Confirmed that when this long-lived token is used to obtain page access tokens, they expire in 60 days.

This is the appropriate workflow, correct?

Comment: So the migration is enabled, you're using the server side oauth flow with the current auth dialog, and still not getting 60 day tokens?

Comment: Correct.  We have some client-size auth mixed in here and there, but the important bits should be server-side and functioning correctly.  (See the updated main question above).  And thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Igy, what are your thoughts?  I'd love to hear your perspective.  And to the downvoter, I'd be interested to hear your constructive criticism on why this is not an appropriate question for SO.

Comment: The page access tokens should be infinite once retrieved via a user's long-lived (~60 day) token - if not it's likely a bug, the problem with those bug reports is that people say 'me too' when the repro steps aren't exactly the same or there's some other edge case at play so it's difficult to see the root cause - i'll take a look and see if this is a known issue

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Igy.  I believe I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've fixed the problem (at least in my scenario).  Two things were required to get this working:

1. We were successfully obtaining long-lived access tokens on the server side.  However, we could not use the long-lived tokens in the client-side API (via /me/accounts) to obtain unexpiring page access tokens.  This may be due to the fact that the client-side never received the updated long-lived access token.

   Regardless, we migrated the "page access token acquisition" code from the client-side to the server-side which seems to have resolved the problem.  (I imagine there must be a way to do this on the client-side, but it may prove difficult to force the client-side API to use the updated long-lived access token instead of the short-lived one.)
2. Our changes seemed to have no effect (at least on our existing test users and test apps) until we completely deleted the our Facebook app from the Facebook user's account (http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications).